# SAS Macro Language

Tags: sas, sas-macro

On SAS, after defining Macro Language, for example,

```
   %macro source(x);
   ......
   %mend source;
```

I want to substitute x for 17 to 63, does there have an easy way to do this instead of key in

```
%source(16);
%source(17);
...
%source(63);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new macro with a do-statement to run you macro a select number of times:

```
%MACRO RunMacro(from, to);
    %DO i = &from. %TO &to.;
        %source(&i.);
    %END;
%MEND RunMacro;

%RunMacro(16, 63);
```